# Time based OTP generation generating wrong key C#

Tags: c#, google-authentication, one-time-password, base32

I've implemented a number of TOTP classes now and they all generate the wrong output. Below I've posted the code I used for the most simple one.

I'd like for it to get implemented and behave just like Google Authenticator - For example like the code https://gauth.apps.gbraad.nl/#main.

So what I want to happen is that in the front end of the application a user will enter his secret "BANANAKEY123" which translates to a base32 string of "IJAU4QKOIFFUKWJRGIZQ====".

Now in the constructor below key would be "BANANAKEY123". Yet for some reason it' not generating the same OTP keys with this code as the GAuth OTP tool does.

The only two reasonable mistakes would be

```
var secretKeyBytes = Base32Encode(secretKey);
```

is wrong or that my timing function is wrong. I checked both and couldn't find the fault in any of those. So could someone please help me in the right direction? Thank you!

```
    public class Totp
{
    private readonly int digits = 6;
    private readonly HMACSHA1 hmac;
    private readonly HMACSHA256 hmac256;
    private readonly Int32 t1 = 30;
    internal int mode;

    private string secret;

    private const string allowedCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567";

    public Totp(string key, int mode)
    {
        secret = key;
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    // defaults to SHA-1
    public Totp(string key)
    {
        secret = key;
        this.mode = 1;
    }


    public Totp(string base32string, Int32 t1, int digits) : this(base32string)
    {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.digits = digits;
    }

    public Totp(string base32string, Int32 t1, int digits, int mode) : this(base32string, mode)
    {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.digits = digits;
    }

    public String getCodeString()
    {
        return GetCode(this.secret, GetInterval(DateTime.UtcNow));
    }

    private static long GetInterval(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        TimeSpan elapsedTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return (long)elapsedTime.TotalSeconds / 30;
    }

    private static string GetCode(string secretKey, long timeIndex)
    {
        var secretKeyBytes = Base32Encode(secretKey);
        HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(secretKeyBytes);
        byte[] challenge = BitConverter.GetBytes(timeIndex);
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(challenge);
        byte[] hash = hmac.ComputeHash(challenge);
        int offset = hash[19] & 0xf;
        int truncatedHash = hash[offset] & 0x7f;
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            truncatedHash <<= 8;
            truncatedHash |= hash[offset + i] & 0xff;
        }
        truncatedHash %= 1000000;
        return truncatedHash.ToString("D6");
    }

    private static byte[] Base32Encode(string source)
    {
        var bits = source.ToUpper().ToCharArray().Select(c =>
            Convert.ToString(allowedCharacters.IndexOf(c), 2).PadLeft(5, '0')).Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);
        return Enumerable.Range(0, bits.Length / 8).Select(i => Convert.ToByte(bits.Substring(i * 8, 8), 2)).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, your `Base32Encode` method is very inefficient (the `ToUpper()` and `ToCharArray()` calls are unnecessary) and using `Aggregate` with `String` instead of `StringBuilder` will cause excessive new string allocations (and run in O(n^n) time).

Comment: Is it a typo in this post that your 'secret key' includes the character `1` but that's not in your `allowedCharacters` set?

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this code for quite some time to generate Time-based OTP, hope it helps.

[**TotpAuthenticationService.cs**](https://gist.github.com/rahmadSammaron/142f9233c967985a149be5c33fe973b3)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Wteen.Infrastructure.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An Time Based Implementation of RFC 6238, a variation from the OTP (One Time Password) with, a default code life time of 30 seconds.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class TotpAuthenticationService
    {
        private readonly Encoding _encoding;
        private readonly int _length;
        private readonly TimeSpan _timestep;
        private readonly DateTime _unixEpoch;

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new Instance of <see cref="TotpAuthenticationService"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="length">The length of the OTP</param>
        /// <param name="duration">The peried of time in which the genartion of a OTP with the result with the same value</param>
        public TotpAuthenticationService(int length, int duration = 30)
        {
            _length = length;
            _encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);
            _timestep = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration);
            _unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The current time step number
        /// </summary>
        private ulong CurrentTimeStepNumber => (ulong)(TimeElapsed.Ticks / _timestep.Ticks);

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of seconds elapsed since midnight UTC of January 1, 1970.
        /// </summary>
        private TimeSpan TimeElapsed => DateTime.UtcNow - _unixEpoch;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="securityToken"></param>
        /// <param name="modifier"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int GenerateCode(byte[] securityToken, string modifier = null)
        {
            if (securityToken == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(securityToken));

            using (var hmacshA1 = new HMACSHA1(securityToken))
            {
                return ComputeTotp(hmacshA1, CurrentTimeStepNumber, modifier);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validating for codes generated during the current and past code generation <see cref="timeSteps"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="securityToken">User's secerct</param>
        /// <param name="code">The code to validate</param>
        /// <param name="timeSteps">The number of time steps the <see cref="code"/> could be validated for.</param>
        /// <param name="channel">Possible channels could be user's email or mobile number where the code will be sent to</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool ValidateCode(byte[] securityToken, int code, int timeSteps, string channel = null)
        {
            if (securityToken == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(securityToken));

            using (var hmacshA1 = new HMACSHA1(securityToken))
            {
                for (var index = -timeSteps; index <= timeSteps; ++index)
                    if (ComputeTotp(hmacshA1, CurrentTimeStepNumber + (ulong)index, channel) == code)
                        return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private byte[] ApplyModifier(byte[] input, string modifier)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modifier))
                return input;

            var bytes = _encoding.GetBytes(modifier);
            var numArray = new byte[checked(input.Length + bytes.Length)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(input, 0, numArray, 0, input.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, numArray, input.Length, bytes.Length);
            return numArray;
        }

        private int ComputeTotp(HashAlgorithm algorithm, ulong timestepNumber, string modifier)
        {
            var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder((long)timestepNumber));
            var hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(ApplyModifier(bytes, modifier));
            var index = hash[hash.Length - 1] & 15;
            return (((hash[index] & sbyte.MaxValue) << 24) | ((hash[index + 1] & byte.MaxValue) << 16) | ((hash[index + 2] & byte.MaxValue) << 8) | (hash[index + 3] & byte.MaxValue)) % (int)Math.Pow(10, _length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add more than just a link? just in case the link goes bad, which will make your answer no longer useful.

Comment: thank you at @Chillie for pointing it out, I am new to this, I will take your suggestion into consideration in the future.

Comment: it's RFC6238 and not 6248 (I edited the code)